# Mongo cannot see libssl and libcrypto files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mongodb

Im using Linux Mint 17.1 and yesterday I tried to upgrade MongoDb.

I upgraded to Mongo 3.4.4 by first downloading the tgz file and copying all the contents of its `bin/` folder to `/user/bin/`.

I then ran `mongo` and got:

```
mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So  I ran:

```
sudo cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
sudo cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
```

I then went to `/usr/lib/` and both files are there:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  1934624 Jun  2 08:53 libcrypto.so.10*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   387272 Jun  2 08:53 libssl.so.10*
```

I then ran 'mongo' again and now I see:

```
mongo: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by mongo)
mongo: /usr/lib/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by mongo)
```

The files are there. How is it possible that mongo cannot see them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you went to https://www.mongodb.com/download-center to download MongoDB.

I suspect that you didn't download the right binary package.  (Perhaps you downloaded the Amazon Linux version, which is selected by default but is not compatible with your operating system.)

At that web page, you should select version "**Ubuntu 14.04 Linux 64-bit x64**" because Ubuntu 14.04 is roughly equivalent to Linux Mint 17.1.  Make sure this is the version you download.

By selecting that version, you'll see the following text (emphasis mine):

> The binary of this version has been compiled with SSL enabled and dynamically linked. **This requires that SSL libraries be installed separately.** See [here](https://www.openssl.org/) for more information on installing OpenSSL.

Make sure you have OpenSSL installed correctly:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libssl1.0.0
```

Once you have the right version and OpenSSL is installed properly, the MongoDB binaries should work as expected.

---

There is an alternative to downloading the binaries manually.  You can follow [this guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) to configure your package manager to install MongoDB.

Remember that you should use the Ubuntu 14.04 instructions because it is mostly compatible with Linux Mint 17.1.